# Creating a list of active connections NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

I'm building an app that can connect to ELK Alarm systems and output the arming status in a react app. I'm able to connect to the alarm panels and I can console log the arming status with my Alarmpanel class:

```
const elkClient = require('elk-client');

class Alarmpanel {
    constructor(siteName, zoneName, host, port, secure, area) {
        this.siteName = siteName;
        this.zoneName = zoneName;
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.secure = secure;
        this.area = area;
        this.armed;
    }

    set armStatus(state) {
        this.armed = state;
        return state;
    }


     connect() {
        const ElkClient = elkClient.ElkClient;

        let client = new ElkClient({
            connection: {
            name: this.zoneName,
            host: this.host,
            port: this.port ,
            secure: this.secure,
            }
        });

        client
            .connect()
            .then(() => client.getArmingStatus())
            .then((data) => {
                const armingdata = data.areas[this.area].armUpState;
                const armBool = this.armingState(armingdata);
                const panelInfo = {
                    name: this.siteName,
                    armed: armBool
                }
                console.log(panelInfo);
                return panelInfo;  
            })

            .catch((err) => console.log("----Connection Error --------"));

    }

            armingState(data) {
            if(data === 49) {
                this.armStatus = false;
                return this.armed;
            } else if (data === 50) {
                this.armStatus = false;
                return this.armed;
            } else if (data === 51) {
                this.armStatus = true;
                return this.armed;
            } else if (data === 52) {
                this.armStatus = true;
                return this.armed;
            } else if (data === 53) {
                this.armStatus = true;
                return this.armed;
            } else if (data === 54) {
                this.armStatus = true;
                return this.armed;
            } else if (data === 48) {
                this.armStatus = false;
                return this.armed;
            }
        }
    }

const site1 = new Alarmpanel("Site1", "Main House", IP , PORT, true, 0);
const site2 = new Alarmpanel("Site2", "Exterior", IP, PORT, true, 1);
const site3 = new Alarmpanel("Site3", "Exterior", IP, PORT, true, 2);
const site4 = new Alarmpanel("Site4", "Guest House", IP , PORT, true, 3);
const site5 = new Alarmpanel("Site5", "Main House", IP, PORT, true, 0);
const site6 = new Alarmpanel("Site6", "Exterior", IP, PORT, true, 1);
const site7 = new Alarmpanel("Site7", "Main House", IP, PORT, true, 0);

site1.connect();
site2.connect();
site3.connect();
site4.connect();
site5.connect();
site6.connect();
site7.connect();
```

When I console log, then I get the correct "arming status" for each of the 7 sites:

[image]

However, I'm trying to access the return value for each site and put the output into a dynamic array. The array of connections should be kept on my express server and my react app should fetch the status for each site from there.

How could I get the return values from Alarmpanel.connect() into an array that I can access. When I declare a global array then I can only access it and get values from inside the .then() callback. If I access it from anywhere else then I just get [].

Comment: You don't return your Promise in connect(), you should! `return client.[...]`. Then you can serially fetch the status of each alarm system in an async function: `await site1.connect(); await site2.connect();` etc. Then you'll be able to store your variables in the then (globally if you want but not ideal), or just return them in the then and assign them outside.

Answer (score 1):

As described in my first comment, you're not returning any promise from your connect function. This means you cannot *wait* for data outside your connect function. Even if you set data globally in the `then`, it'll only be accessible from this point on, and I assume your `console.log()` of the the global variable had already printed, since you were not waiting for the connections to establish.

Here's a very rough fix of your code:

```
const elkClient = require('elk-client');

class Alarmpanel {
    constructor(siteName, zoneName, host, port, secure, area) {
        this.siteName = siteName;
        this.zoneName = zoneName;
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.secure = secure;
        this.area = area;
        this.armed;
    }

    set armStatus(state) {
        this.armed = state;
        return state;
    }


     connect() {
        const ElkClient = elkClient.ElkClient;

        let client = new ElkClient({
            connection: {
            name: this.zoneName,
            host: this.host,
            port: this.port ,
            secure: this.secure,
            }
        });

        return client
            .connect()
            .then(() => client.getArmingStatus())
            .then((data) => {
                const armingdata = data.areas[this.area].armUpState;
                const armBool = this.armingState(armingdata);
                const panelInfo = {
                    name: this.siteName,
                    armed: armBool
                }
                return panelInfo;  
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log("----Connection Error --------"));

    }

    armingState(data) {
        if(data === 49) {
            this.armStatus = false;
            return this.armed;
        } else if (data === 50) {
            this.armStatus = false;
            return this.armed;
        } else if (data === 51) {
            this.armStatus = true;
            return this.armed;
        } else if (data === 52) {
            this.armStatus = true;
            return this.armed;
        } else if (data === 53) {
            this.armStatus = true;
            return this.armed;
        } else if (data === 54) {
            this.armStatus = true;
            return this.armed;
        } else if (data === 48) {
            this.armStatus = false;
            return this.armed;
        }
    }
}

const site1 = new Alarmpanel("Site1", "Main House", IP , PORT, true, 0);
const site2 = new Alarmpanel("Site2", "Exterior", IP, PORT, true, 1);
const site3 = new Alarmpanel("Site3", "Exterior", IP, PORT, true, 2);
const site4 = new Alarmpanel("Site4", "Guest House", IP , PORT, true, 3);
const site5 = new Alarmpanel("Site5", "Main House", IP, PORT, true, 0);
const site6 = new Alarmpanel("Site6", "Exterior", IP, PORT, true, 1);
const site7 = new Alarmpanel("Site7", "Main House", IP, PORT, true, 0);

async function connect() {
    const statuses = [
        await site1.connect(),
        await site2.connect(),
        await site3.connect(),
        await site4.connect(),
        await site5.connect(),
        await site6.connect(),
        await site7.connect(),
    ];
    console.log(statuses);
}

connect();
```

I'm not using any fancy promise stuff on purpose, but you can look at Promise.all to improve this code!

Comment: Awesome this worked. Thank you so much! I tried to vote but because I'm still new I'm not allowed to. I'll make up for it as soon as I reached 15 points!!